# How to prohibit compiler to precompute product of constant values

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a current controller using a ATmega328.
For the control algorithm I need to convert the desired current into that value, the ADC would measure if the desired current flows. So instead of controlling the current it's more a kind of "controlling" the measured ADC value.
Nevertheless it is necessary to convert the desired current in it's equivalent ADC-value.
Therefore I have defined all parameter included in the measurement chain:

```
#define CTRL_SHUNT_GAIN             (20UL)                  // 20mV/A -> R=0.02Ohm (A->mV)
#define ADC_REF_VOLTAGE             (1100UL)                // mV
#define CTRL_ADC_V2ADC              1024UL/ADC_REF_VOLTAGE  // 1024=U_ADCref (mV->ADC)
#define CTRL_ADC_ADC2V              ADC_REF_VOLTAGE/1024UL  // 1024=U_ADCref (ADC->mV)

// conversion
#define CTRL_I2ADC(cur)             ((int16_t)((int32_t)cur*CTRL_SHUNT_GAIN*CTRL_ADC_V2ADC/1000UL))
```

In the code later I call the control algorith and handover the (converted) desired value, the last ADC measurement and a pointer to the controller structure, containing the gains and so on.

```
outputA = controlAlgorithm(CTRL_I2ADC(desA), adcSampling.values[0], &ctrlA);
```

The problem I have is, that the compiler precalculates the right part of the multiplication (`CTRL_SHUNT_GAIN*CTRL_ADC_V2ADC/1000UL`), which - correctly - yields zero (`20*1024/1100/1000=0`). But i.e. let `cur` be `8000 mA`, this conversion should provide `8000*20*1024/1100/1000=148`.
So my question ist, how to tell the compiler, not to precompute the "constant" part of the multiplication.

Or do I need to define all the stuff in an other way?

**Edit**
inside `controlAlgorith` I produce a debug output:

```
// computes output value depending on input error in mA
int16_t controlAlgorithm(int16_t des, int16_t act, controller_t *ctrl){
int32_t ctrlOut;

// debug output
uart0SendInt(des);
uart0SendString("\t");
uart0SendInt(act);
uart0SendString("\t");
...
}
```

calling it like this:

```
outputB = controlAlgorithm(desB, adcSampling.values[1], &ctrlB);
outputB = controlAlgorithm(CTRL_I2ADC(desB), adcSampling.values[1], &ctrlB);
```

gives me the output:

```
8000    50
32      50
```

Comment: Did you try this: `(cur*CTRL_SHUNT_GAIN*CTRL_ADC_V2ADC)/1000UL` ? The issue is in the division.

Comment: It's not about whether the compiler precomputes or not, it's about correctly using parentheses to specify the order of operations.

Comment: The `CTRL_ADC_V2ADC` and `CTRL_ADC_ADC2V` macros don't seem good.  By themselves they evaluate to `0`.  You seem to be relying on using it in another expression so that the the `1024UL` will be part of a subexpression evaluated first, but that is extremely confusing and error-prone.

Comment: BTW: Macro definitions with operators should always be between parenthesis: Eg: `#define FOO BAR+2` is bad, `#define FOO (BAR+2)` is OK.

Comment: However your macro as it stands *does* yield 148 when called as `CTRL_I2ADC(8000)`: https://godbolt.org/z/7WsMPj.  I suspect there is some other problem, or your test case varies in some way that you haven't shown (e.g. `CTRL_I2ADC(4000+4000)` will mess up due to the fact that you didn't parenthesize `cur`).  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: A safer way to do this sort of fixed-point arithmetic: instead of trying to define a "constant" macro and multiplying by it, use a function-like macro.  So not `foo*CTRL_ADC_V2ADC`, but instead `#define CTRL_ADC_V2ADC(x) (((x)*1024UL)/ADC_REF_VOLTAGE)` and then `CTRL_ADC_V2ADC(foo)`.

Comment: I would suggest making all your constants into `double` values, do the conversion as a `double` operation, then convert/cast to the required integer type. As it stands, your expressions like `1024UL/ADC_REF_VOLTAGE` (which will be 1) and `ADC_REF_VOLTAGE/1024UL` (which will be zero) are likely to cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm not sure that chip has hardware floating-point support, so this may be a non-starter.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: I think, only parenthesis won't solve the issue, because the macro is not ordered by multiplications first and then the division. Using `CTRL_ADC_V2ADC` will introduce a division. In a previous version, each variable was put into parenthesis. Maybe the only possibility is, not to use nested macros.

Comment: @Adrian Mole: The ATmega328 is a 8bit controller and I have to be fast in my calculations, so floating point is not an option.

Comment: I think you need to explain more clearly what these macros are meant to compute.  But "prohibit the compiler precomputing" is definitely not the issue.  By the "as if rule" precomputation will be done only if it yields exactly the same result as doing the same computation at run time.  So it's on you to ensure your macros expand to an expression that does the right operations in the right order.  Then "precomputation" is moot.

Comment: Still not a [mcve].  It depends on how `desB` is defined, for instance; if it's a macro whose expansion is not properly parenthesized, then this will fail as I mentioned earlier.  You should be able to reproduce this with a small program that just `printf`s the values, then anybody can test it without needing a microcontroller.

Comment: From what you have shown , the output from the second run should be what you indent to - `148`. Could you create a small full program, including all the `#include`s and small `int main()` with the problem, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/hMvbhq)? What compiler are you using?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on a normal platform? How long is `UL` and default `int`? What happens if you cast it to about the same type as on a normal platform?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: to explain the intension of this macros: I want to realize a current control using a full H-bridge driver. To control the current I need to compute first the current equivalent ADC-value, that would be measured, if the desired current flows. So the macro is the "inverted" feedback loop. The feedback loop is a chain and consists of a shunt resistor R (current I to voltage Vadc), the uC ADC (voltage Vadc to sample value n). So (I*R)/Vref*1024 yields the current equivalent ADC-value (divison by 1000 is because I is in mA)

Comment: using "function-like-macros" solved the issue.
The missmatch between 32 of my prompt and my expected 148 was my fault. Sorry and thanks for your help.

Comment: @NateEldredge: When I take your example [https://godbolt.org/z/7WsMPj](https://godbolt.org/z/7WsMPj) and change the compiler to AVR GCC 5.4.0 the result becomes 0. But I'm not sure if this is related to the macro or if it is related to the printf-function. Maybe this funktion is not known by AVR-GCC!?

Comment: 0 is the exit code of the compiler (indicating successful compilation), not the output of the program.  godbolt cannot actually run programs compiled for AVR, only x86.